# Foreach with conditional

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to avoid scripts (I am under the impression that may have a performance impact?) so would ideally like to do something like the following:

```
"foreach": "ctx.payload.aggregations.name.buckets",
  "condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.doc_count" : {
        "gte": 10
       }
     }
   },
...
```

but I can't seem to get it working. Is it possible to do this?
If there is a script-based solution that would also be appreciated, but as I said I am trying to avoid this if at all possible.

Thanks!

Comment: By script you mean `painless` script ?

Comment: Yes, apologies.

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible without a [transform step](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-script.html) (which require a painless script)

Comment: You should most probably explain in plain english the behaviour you are willing to observe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

I am not sure there is a solution without a painless script.

## Script solution

Add a [transform step](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-script.html) to your watcher, to filter out the what you do not want.

The following filter out number below 5.

```json
{
  "transform" : {
    "script" : """
    def list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

    return list.stream().filter(c-> c>5).collect(Collectors.toList());
    """
  }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that. Thanks Paulo.

Comment: Sorry mate, but I am not all knowing maybe someone will come up with a clever answer. But at least for now you are not stuck